# Dimension mismatch error while storing feature extraction data in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, feature-extraction, mismatch

I'm trying to store features of all the images extracted using LBP in a matrix.
But it is giving me this error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in fe1 (line 10)
>          A(i, :) = LBP(img);

Here are my codes:

`fe.m`

```
clc;
clear all;

pat = 'D:/modified database';
Angry = dir([pat '/anger']);
Andry = Angry(3:end);
A = zeros(255, length(Andry));

for i = 1:length(Andry)
    img = imread(Andry(i).name);
    A(:, i) = LBP(img);
end

display(A);
```

`LBP.m`

```
function LBP0 = LBP(I)
   I = imresize(I, [256,256]);
   I = rgb2gray(I);
   m = size(I,1);
   n = size(I,2);
   for i = 2:m-1
       for j = 2:n-1
           J0 = I(i,j);
           I3(i-1,j-1) = I(i-1,j-1)>J0;
           I3(i-1,j) = I(i-1,j)>J0;
           I3(i-1,j+1) = I(i-1,j+1)>J0; 
           I3(i,j+1) = I(i,j+1)>J0;
           I3(i+1,j+1) = I(i+1,j+1)>J0; 
           I3(i+1,j) = I(i+1,j)>J0; 
           I3(i+1,j-1) = I(i+1,j-1)>J0; 
           I3(i,j-1) = I(i,j-1)>J0;
           LBP0(i,j) = I3(i-1,j-1)*2^7 + I3(i-1,j)*2^6 + I3(i-1,j+1)*2^5 + I3(i,j+1)*2^4 + I3(i+1,j+1)*2^3+I3(i+1,j)*2^2 + I3(i+1,j-1)*2^1 + I3(i,j-1)*2^0;
       end
   end
end
```

I think there is some problem with the dimensions of matrix A.
Please help me with the code.
Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

`A` hols few 2D matrices, so `A` needs to be a 3D matrix...

1. Modify `A = zeros(255, length(Andry));` to `A = zeros(255, 255, length(Andry));`
2. Modify `A(:, i) = LBP(img);` to `A(:, :, i) = LBP(img);`

---

I think the following code should work:

`fe.m`

```
clc;
clear all;

pat = 'D:/modified database';
Angry = dir([pat '/anger']);
Andry = Angry(3:end);
A = zeros(255, 255, length(Andry));

for i = 1:length(Andry)
    img = imread(Andry(i).name);
    A(:, :, i) = LBP(img);
end

display(A);
```

---

In case images have different dimensions, you can use [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html) instead of 3D matrix:

`fe.m`

```
clc;
clear all;

pat = 'D:/modified database';
Angry = dir([pat '/anger']);
Andry = Angry(3:end);
A = cell(1, length(Andry)); %Allocate cell array

for i = 1:length(Andry)
    img = imread(Andry(i).name);
    A{i} = LBP(img); %Store LBP(img) in index i of cell array A
end

%Use loop to display cell array elements.
for i = 1:length(A)
    display(A{i});
end
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error at line A(:,:,i)=LBP(img);

Comment: Is it necessary that the size of LBP output should be same for all images?

Comment: In case size is different, you can use cell array instead of 3D matrix.

Answer (score 0):

LBP function returns a 255*255 matrix while A is a 255*(number of images/files in your Angry dir) matrix. If you want to save LBP result for every image, you should change the dimensions of matrix A.